# How to prove that $∃x J(x)$ and $J(m)$ are not logically equivalent?

Tags: logic, predicate-logic

I'm supposed to use counter models to establish that the two sentences $∃x J(x)$ and $J(m)$ are not equivalent. My initial work is this, does it seem right?

> Domain: Lionel Messi, Cristiano Ronaldo
>
> J(x): Plays for Manchester United
>
> m: Lionel Messi
>
> ∃x J(x) would be true for Cristiano Ronaldo, but J(m) would be false
> because Messi does not play for Manchester United. Thus, proving that
> the sentences are not equivalent logically.

Another question: how big or small should I make my domains when trying to make a counter model? For instance, should it be a list of premier league players (Kevin De Bruyne, Cristiano Ronaldo, etc.) or should it be a broader domain like 'Domain: Premier league players.' Is there an easier and less confusing way?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: The Messi vs Ronaldo counter-example is correct.

Comment: Another example will be with domain the natural numbers: let $J(x)$ interpreted with "x is Even" and let $m$ be $1$.

Comment: Variants of your example with bigger domains would also be correct. Technically one is as good as another. Psychologically, I prefer small examples; they make it clearer that you understand the essence of the issue,

Answer (score 0):

> > Domain: Lionel Messi, Cristiano Ronaldo
> >
> > J(x): Plays for Manchester United
> >
> > m: Lionel Messi
> >
> > ∃x J(x) would be true for Cristiano Ronaldo

Less confusingly: $∃x J(x)$ is true, not merely for Ronaldo, but for the entire domain including Messi. On the other hand, $J(x)$ is true merely for Ronaldo.

> Another question: how big or small should I make my domains when
> trying to make a counter model? For instance, should it be a list of
> premier league players (Kevin De Bruyne, Cristiano Ronaldo, etc.) or
> should it be a broader domain like 'Domain: Premier league players' ?

I don't think this matters. Alternatively, I like Mauro's arithmetical suggestion above, and here's another one: let the domain of discourse be $\{m,7\}$ and define $J(x)$ such that $J(x)$ is true if and only if $x=7.$